# Download in android

Tags: android

I am trying to build an application in which I Am playing videos and images simultaneously. Every one hour or so the app has to download materials from internet. so to use the new materials I am trying to make it restart. I have implemented a runnable and put the code for download and restart in the run method. The problem is that the app freezes soon after start-

```
synchronized public void run() {
    download("http://www.justieltsshaddi.com/pankaj/list.txt",
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/alpha/list.txt");
    File beta = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/beta/");
    File betalist = new File(beta + "/list.txt");
    File alpha = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/alpha/");
    File alphalist = new File(alpha + "/list.txt");
    if (alphalist.lastModified() == betalist.lastModified()) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        FileReader inAlpha = new FileReader(alphalist);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inAlpha);
        String s;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Starting Download...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            download("http://www.justieltsshaddi.com/pankaj" + "/" + s,
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/alpha/"
                            + s);
        }
        // stop the activity to rename folders
        Toast.makeText(this, "Download done. Restarting...",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("Pankaj", "Download Done");
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        finish();

        Log.d("Pankaj", "MainActivity Killed");
        // rename alpha to beta
        deleteSubFolders(beta.toString());
        alpha.renameTo(beta);
        if (!alpha.exists()) {
            alpha.mkdir();
        }
        File upper = new File(alpha + "/upper/");
        if (!upper.exists())
            upper.mkdirs();
        File lower = new File(alpha + "/lower/");
        if (!lower.exists())
            lower.mkdirs();
        // restart the activity
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        startActivity(intent);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

any help is appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use Aysnc Task to download the files

```
private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
    try {

        //do your download 
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        download("http://www.justieltsshaddi.com/pankaj" + "/" + s,
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/alpha/"
                        + s);
         }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

call the download task as below 
    // execute this when the downloader must be fired
    DownloadFile downloadFile = new DownloadFile();
    downloadFile.execute("the url to the file you want to download");

may be thinking of firing the download task in loop.

Comment: There is a slight problem. I need to wait for the downloads to finish before processing further.

Comment: you can invoke executeOnExecutor to serialize it and have your logic

Comment: This is what I have done. The execution doesn't proceed beyond first line.

Comment: protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
  download(sUrl[0] + "/list.txt",
    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/alpha/list.txt");

Comment: adding Thread.sleep() in the while loop seems to have done the trick. But as of now it is running only on the emulator not on the device.

Comment: Is there a way to execute repeatedly after a set time?

Comment: Use 'handler' and 'sendMessageDelayed' with appropriate delay

Answer (score 0):

Use Service and Alarm Manager

```
          Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
          cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

          Intent intent = new Intent(this, reciever.class);

          PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, _id, i, 0);

          AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
          //for 30 mint 60*60*1000
          alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                       60*60*1000, pi );
```

In broadcast reciever start the service

```
public class reciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

}
```